# Avoiding Duplicate Content on my website (for blog posts and testimonials)

Tags: seo, duplicates, search-engine

We say that **"Duplicate Content is a bad thing for Search Engines"**.

On my website (http://www.prezzio.net), I display a selection of 6 blog posts on the bottom of my home page. Clicking on each of them allow the visitor to reach the full blog post.

I think this is a `Duplicate Content` problem, isn't ? Because these 6 resumes are displayed on the home page but also on the blog section. What can I do to avoid penalization by Search Engines ?

I have the same problem for my testimonials: on my home page I display 2 of my testimonials. On another page I display all of my testimonials. So I have `Duplicate Content` for these 2 testimonials.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Define "selection" - is it the entire blog posts that are visible on the front page?

Comment: Not the entire blog posts but only 6 (a selection of 6 best blog posts).

Comment: But each of the 6 blog posts in full?

Comment: No, only the first x lines are showed on the home page. Then you have the text `Read more` to access the full blog post.

Comment: If search engines would punish *that*, they would be punishing any blog with a front page. It's very unlikely that this is the case. "Duplicate content" generally refers to multiple URLs where exactly the same content is visible

Comment: That's what I think but I wonder if something can be done (no follow link?).

Comment: I don't think you need to do anything really

Comment: Nice idea with the team animation by the way. The video looks slightly off, though, subtly blurry, as if it were resized incorrectly

Comment: Thanks anyway for your opinion. However I hope some other users can confirm what we think.

Comment: Really? What browser are you using ?

Comment: Chrome on OS X. This is what it looks like for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVIGj.jpg The logo looks blurry

Comment: You're unlikely to get more than opinions on this matter - Google says in its [guidelines on duplicate content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en) that "substantive blocks of content" are counted. There's not going to be an exact measure how much makes a "substantive block".

Comment: Something's strange because on my computer, your screenshot does not look blurry at all...?

Comment: It's subtle but it's there: the logo and the word "Prezzio" are less crisp around the edges than they could be. It's more visible enlarged: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1fH1X.png It's either the scaling, or compression artifacts. I personally would put the logo in a PNG instead of the video. But then I'm a perfectionist about these things, by occupation

Comment: Thanks anyway I'll try to correct that. I am also a perfectionist.